# remove particular keys from dictionary

Tags: python

I have this array a = ["one", "two"] and I want to match these values in dictionary I have which looks like this

```
b = {one: "something", two: "something2", three: "something3"}
```

I want to match this key and remove the keys from the dictionary

In the end it will be something like this

```
{'three': 'something3'}
```

what I have tried is this

```
for t in a:
    b = b.pop(t, None)
    return b
```

Just want to know if there is a better way to do this

Comment: `b = b.pop(t, None)` and now your `b` dictionary is gone...

Comment: why looping if you return immediately?

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a new dict:

```
c = {key: value for key, value in b.items() if key not in a}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use `del`

```
a = ["one", "two"]
b = {"one": "something", "two": "something2", "three": "something3"}

for key in a:
    del b[key]

print(b)
# {'three': 'something3'}
```